# Why can't I parse this JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below JSON string:

```
var billjson = "({'posts' : [{'Id' :'      7553','Code' :'1186 ','Address' :' GGGG 39Α                    ','Name' : ' GGGG NAME 3                               ','Description' : ' G 3    ','EntrySeason' : ' GGGGG 08-09      ','Period' : ' 10/2009   ','Revenue' : '      4.10'},{'Id' :'      7553','Code' :'1186 ','Address' :' GGGG 39Α                    ','Name' : ' FFFF NAME 3                               ','Description' : ' F 3    ','EntrySeason' : ' FFFF 08-09      ','Period' : ' 10/2009   ','Revenue' : '      4.10'}]})"
```

and I'm trying to create a JSON object using the code:

```
var mybilljson = jQuery.parseJSON( billjson );
```

but the result at the console is:

> Uncaught Invalid JSON:

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals and property names have to use double-quotes in JSON, but you're using single quotes. The parentheses aren't allowed to be there either.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the paranthesis in order to have valid JSON. Also you must use double quotes:

```
var billjson= '{"posts": [{"Id": "7553","Code": "1186","Address": "GGGG39Α","Name": "GGGGNAME3","Description": "G3","EntrySeason": "GGGGG08-09","Period": "10/2009","Revenue": "4.10"},{"Id": "7553","Code": "1186","Address": "GGGG39Α","Name": "FFFFNAME3","Description": "F3","EntrySeason": "FFFF08-09","Period": "10/2009","Revenue": "4.10"}]}';
var mybilljson = jQuery.parseJSON( billjson );
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using single-quotes rather than double-quotes around field names and string values, your JSON string is invalid because of the surrounding parens: `()`.

Kill the surrounding parens and change the single-quotes to double quotes:

```
var billjson = '{"posts" : [{"Id" :"      7553","Code" :"1186 ", ...
```